# EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) JVM from JNI?

Tags: java, visual-c++, java-native-interface, fatal-error

I wrote some native methods in a vc++ with JNI to be accessed from java.  Two of my three methods work perfectly fine with no issues.  My last method, however, has been causing the following error message when i call it during runtime:

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x61e06550, pid=3408, tid=4796
#
# JRE version: 7.0-b147
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (21.0-b17 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0xa6550]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
```

Here is my native method's code (in vc++):

```
JNIEXPORT jcharArray JNICALL Java_jniusb_Main_receiveData (JNIEnv *env, jclass, jchar dataIndex)
{
    DWORD BytesWritten = 0;
    DWORD BytesRead = 0;
    unsigned char OutputPacketBuffer[65];   
    unsigned char InputPacketBuffer[65];    

    static jcharArray ReturnPacketBuffer;
    jchar temp[65];

    //send 'receive data' command to the firmware (OutputPacketBuffer[1])
    WriteFile(WriteHandle, &OutputPacketBuffer, 65, &BytesWritten, 0);
        //retrieve data from firmware
    ReadFile(ReadHandle, &InputPacketBuffer, 65, &BytesRead, 0);        

        for(int i=0;i<64;i++) 
    {
        temp[i] = jchar(InputPacketBuffer[i+1]);
    }

    (*env).SetCharArrayRegion(ReturnPacketBuffer, 0, 64, temp);
    return ReturnPacketBuffer;
}
```

My Java code looks like this (abridged of course):

```
public static native char[] receiveData(char dataIndex);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    char vid = 0x4d8;
    char pid = 0x3f;

    //check if read/write handles were retrieved 
    if(connectHid(vid, pid) == true)
    {
        System.out.println("connected!!!");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("not connected...");
    }


    char[] test = new char[64];
    char[] receivetest = new char[64];

    char length = 0x03;
    char dataIndex = 0x81;

    test[0] = 0x80;
    test[1] = 0x80;
    sendData(test, length);
    receivetest = receiveData(dataIndex);
```

Like I said before, the other methods (i.e. connect and senddata) work fine and but I get the error from the receiveData method.  After some debugging I discovered that the error goes away when I comment out the line:

```
(*env).SetCharArrayRegion(ReturnPacketBuffer, 0, 64, temp);
```

in my native code (of course the data never gets returned in this case...).  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: for(int i=0;i<64;i++) should be for (int i=0; i<65; i++)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aren't you missing something like
`ReturnPacketBuffer = (*env)->NewCharArray(env, 64);`

Comment: I never used JNI before so I didn't know about this but it seemed to clear everything up, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The exception code is for uninitalized memory access, as a hint, look for indexing out of bounds.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i=0;i<64;i++) 
{
    temp[i] = jchar(InputPacketBuffer[i+1]);
}
```

`temp` can hold 65 elements of type `jchar`. They initially hold some garbage values. With the above loop, you try to fill from **0** to **63** elements. The last element is left unfilled and is left with the garbage value which it had initially.

```
(*env).SetCharArrayRegion(ReturnPacketBuffer, 0, 64, temp);
```

Probably, the above statement is working on value at the 64th index of `temp` and is failing because of garbage in it. Try giving an index less than 64, it works, IMO. Or fill the 64th index also with a valid value by incrementing the for loop iteration to one another iteration.

Comment: I don't think 64 signifies an index, but a length. So, this should set 64 chars.