# Tomcat JVM crash exception_access_violation, possibly caused by imageio / CeWolf / JFreeChart?

Tags: tomcat, jfreechart, javax.imageio, cewolf

I have web applications running on Tomcats on several servers, which crash Tomcat with EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION, something like once a month per server. The crash dump seems to indicate there may be an issue with imageio, which is used by CeWolf (JFreeChart) JSPs in a Tomcat webapp.

I am using

- the currently latest Java 6 (6.0_37-b06),
- Tomcat with native code almost latest version 7.0.32 (the bugfixes in 7.0.33 (latest) all don't seem to be related),
- CeWolf almost latest version 1.1.12 (again, the bugfixes in 1.1.13 (latest) all seem unrelated),
- WinXP SP3 32bit with latest patches
- running in a VM on VMWare ESXi 4.1 u3 (latest patches installed)

I found some similar questions here, where the solution was always: update to latest Java. Well, it is the latest Java 6. What could cause this / how could this be fixed? Thanks a lot for any input!

There is the additional issue, that Windows service automatic restart doesn't kick in on this one, even though that works fine for other service issues. Somehow Windows seems to think the service shutdown in this case was intentional or so. As a side question: Any ideas on this? Besides writing my own service checker watchdog (as service or scheduled task)...

Stack dump (had to remove some thread entries due to post length limit):

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x49434bdf, pid=1944, tid=352
#
# JRE version: 6.0_37-b06
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (20.12-b01 mixed mode windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [tcnative-1.dll+0x4bdf]
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00c06800):  JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=352, stack(0x48b90000,0x48c00000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x00000020

Registers:
EAX=0x00000000, EBX=0x0000006f, ECX=0x4abe2a10, EDX=0x490e3000
ESP=0x48bff7e4, EBP=0x48bff7f8, ESI=0x00000000, EDI=0x4ea10068
EIP=0x49434bdf, EFLAGS=0x00010206

Top of Stack: (sp=0x48bff7e4)
0x48bff7e4:   490e3000 48bff800 00000000 00c06800
0x48bff7f4:   48bff820 48bff838 016ba033 0000006f
0x48bff804:   48bff820 4ea10068 00000000 00000000
0x48bff814:   0000006f 1970c068 1970eff8 435c4a58
0x48bff824:   00000001 1970cfe8 1970f038 00000000
0x48bff834:   00000000 48bff990 016387e8 4ea10068
0x48bff844:   00000000 1970bd10 6d7f2b66 00000000
0x48bff854:   00c06800 1970bd10 0190f460 00000000 

Instructions: (pc=0x49434bdf)
0x49434bbf:   5d 1c 85 db 76 2b 8b 47 18 8b d3 2b d6 89 55 08
0x49434bcf:   8b 57 10 03 d6 03 55 18 8d 4d 08 51 8b 4f 0c 52
0x49434bdf:   8b 50 20 51 ff d2 85 c0 75 10 03 75 08 3b f3 72
0x49434bef:   d5 5b 5f 8b c6 5e 5d c2 18 00 3d 77 11 01 00 0f 


Register to memory mapping:

EAX=0x00000000 is an unknown value
EBX=0x0000006f is an unknown value
ECX=0x4abe2a10 is an unknown value
EDX=0x490e3000 is an unknown value
ESP=0x48bff7e4 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00c06800
EBP=0x48bff7f8 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00c06800
ESI=0x00000000 is an unknown value
EDI=0x4ea10068 is an unknown value


Stack: [0x48b90000,0x48c00000],  sp=0x48bff7e4,  free space=445k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [tcnative-1.dll+0x4bdf]  Java_org_apache_tomcat_jni_Socket_sendbb+0x4f
J  org.apache.tomcat.jni.Socket.sendbb(JII)I
J  org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalAprOutputBuffer.flushBuffer()V
j  javax.imageio.stream.MemoryCacheImageOutputStream.flushBefore(J)V+47
j  javax.imageio.stream.MemoryCacheImageOutputStream.close()V+15
j  javax.imageio.stream.ImageInputStreamImpl.finalize()V+8
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [jvm.dll+0xfb7cb]
V  [jvm.dll+0x18d3d1]
V  [jvm.dll+0xfb84d]
V  [jvm.dll+0x96301]
V  [jvm.dll+0x990c9]
C  [java.dll+0x2100]  Java_java_lang_ref_Finalizer_invokeFinalizeMethod+0x39
J  java.lang.ref.Finalizer.runFinalizer()V
V  [jvm.dll+0xfb7cb]
V  [jvm.dll+0x18d3d1]
V  [jvm.dll+0xfb971]
V  [jvm.dll+0xfb9cb]
V  [jvm.dll+0xb5e99]
V  [jvm.dll+0x119ab4]
V  [jvm.dll+0x14209c]
C  [MSVCR71.dll+0x9565]  endthreadex+0xa0
C  [kernel32.dll+0xb729]  GetModuleFileNameA+0x1ba

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
J  org.apache.tomcat.jni.Socket.sendbb(JII)I
J  org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalAprOutputBuffer.flushBuffer()V
J  org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalAprOutputBuffer.flush()V
J  org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.action(Lorg/apache/coyote/ActionCode;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
J  org.apache.coyote.Response.action(Lorg/apache/coyote/ActionCode;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
J  org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(Z)V
J  org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flush()V
j  org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.flush()V+4
j  javax.imageio.stream.MemoryCacheImageOutputStream.flushBefore(J)V+47
j  javax.imageio.stream.MemoryCacheImageOutputStream.close()V+15
j  javax.imageio.stream.ImageInputStreamImpl.finalize()V+8
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
J  java.lang.ref.Finalizer.invokeFinalizeMethod(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
J  java.lang.ref.Finalizer.runFinalizer()V
J  java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run()V
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x4c15b400 JavaThread "http-apr-8080-exec-16537" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2348, stack(0x4be40000,0x4beb0000)]
  0x4c0f4000 JavaThread "http-apr-8080-exec-16536" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4024, stack(0x4bc80000,0x4bcf0000)]
  0x4c039c00 JavaThread "http-apr-8080-exec-16535" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2568, stack(0x4bc10000,0x4bc80000)]
  0x4bef9c00 JavaThread "http-apr-8080-exec-16534" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=256, stack(0x4bba0000,0x4bc10000)]
  0x48fc8800 JavaThread "http-apr-8080-exec-16533" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4068, stack(0x4bb30000,0x4bba0000)]
  0x4c15ac00 JavaThread "http-apr-8080-exec-16532" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3092, stack(0x4bac0000,0x4bb30000)]
  0x4c224c00 JavaThread "http-apr-8080-exec-16531" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2148, stack(0x4ba50000,0x4bac0000)]
  0x4c36a000 JavaThread "http-apr-8080-exec-16530" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1872, stack(0x4b9e0000,0x4ba50000)]
  0x4c4b9800 JavaThread "http-apr-8080-exec-16529" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3640, stack(0x4a540000,0x4a5b0000)]
  0x4c488c00 JavaThread "http-apr-8080-exec-16528" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2108, stack(0x4a4d0000,0x4a540000)]
  0x4c4a5c00 JavaThread "MySQL Statement Cancellation Timer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3120, stack(0x4f5c0000,0x4f630000)]
  0x4c2ff800 JavaThread "MySQL Statement Cancellation Timer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2988, stack(0x4f240000,0x4f2b0000)]
  0x4933d000 JavaThread "MySQL Statement Cancellation Timer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=920, stack(0x4e960000,0x4e9d0000)]
  0x4c4b9400 JavaThread "MySQL Statement Cancellation Timer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1396, stack(0x4e8f0000,0x4e960000)]
  0x4c282000 JavaThread "MySQL Statement Cancellation Timer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3372, stack(0x4dee0000,0x4df50000)]
  0x4c263400 JavaThread "MySQL Statement Cancellation Timer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3624, stack(0x4f1d0000,0x4f240000)]
  0x4c2c4c00 JavaThread "MySQL Statement Cancellation Timer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3204, stack(0x4e7a0000,0x4e810000)]
  0x4c0d9000 JavaThread "MySQL Statement Cancellation Timer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3520, stack(0x4e810000,0x4e880000)]
  0x4c42d800 JavaThread "MySQL Statement Cancellation Timer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3328, stack(0x4df50000,0x4dfc0000)]
  0x4c059400 JavaThread "MySQL Statement Cancellation Timer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2332, stack(0x4dcb0000,0x4dd20000)]
  0x493d6800 JavaThread "MySQL Statement Cancellation Timer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=640, stack(0x4dc40000,0x4dcb0000)]
  0x4c4ef400 JavaThread "MySQL Statement Cancellation Timer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3072, stack(0x4dbd0000,0x4dc40000)]
  0x4c299400 JavaThread "MySQL Statement Cancellation Timer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2196, stack(0x4db60000,0x4dbd0000)]
  0x4c1ccc00 JavaThread "MySQL Statement Cancellation Timer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2080, stack(0x4da80000,0x4daf0000)]
  0x4c2ca400 JavaThread "MySQL Statement Cancellation Timer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2816, stack(0x4f710000,0x4f780000)]
  0x4c45d800 JavaThread "MySQL Statement Cancellation Timer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2604, stack(0x4f6a0000,0x4f710000)]
  0x4bf5b400 JavaThread "MySQL Statement Cancellation Timer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2268, stack(0x4f630000,0x4f6a0000)]
  0x4c1b5800 JavaThread "MySQL Statement Cancellation Timer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2936, stack(0x4daf0000,0x4db60000)]
  0x4bf85800 JavaThread "MySQL Statement Cancellation Timer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3112, stack(0x4f550000,0x4f5c0000)]
  0x4c2f3000 JavaThread "MySQL Statement Cancellation Timer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2140, stack(0x4f320000,0x4f390000)]
  0x4c2fd800 JavaThread "MySQL Statement Cancellation Timer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3248, stack(0x4f4e0000,0x4f550000)]
  0x4c374c00 JavaThread "MySQL Statement Cancellation Timer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3300, stack(0x4f470000,0x4f4e0000)]
  0x4c53bc00 JavaThread "MySQL Statement Cancellation Timer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2072, stack(0x4f400000,0x4f470000)]
  0x4c2ac400 JavaThread "MySQL Statement Cancellation Timer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1368, stack(0x4f390000,0x4f400000)]
  0x4c1e7800 JavaThread "MySQL Statement Cancellation Timer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2076, stack(0x4f2b0000,0x4f320000)]
  0x4c126400 JavaThread "MySQL Statement Cancellation Timer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2528, stack(0x4dd20000,0x4dd90000)]
  0x492a6400 JavaThread "pool-2-thread-15" [_thread_blocked, id=3320, stack(0x4d8d0000,0x4d940000)]
  0x4c38bc00 JavaThread "pool-2-thread-14" [_thread_blocked, id=2896, stack(0x4d860000,0x4d8d0000)]
  0x4bfef400 JavaThread "pool-2-thread-13" [_thread_blocked, id=2932, stack(0x4d7f0000,0x4d860000)]
  0x48f23000 JavaThread "pool-2-thread-12" [_thread_blocked, id=2836, stack(0x4e730000,0x4e7a0000)]
  0x48f21400 JavaThread "pool-2-thread-11" [_thread_blocked, id=3908, stack(0x4e6c0000,0x4e730000)]
  0x491b2800 JavaThread "pool-2-thread-10" [_thread_blocked, id=468, stack(0x4e650000,0x4e6c0000)]
  0x491b0400 JavaThread "pool-2-thread-9" [_thread_blocked, id=3504, stack(0x4e5e0000,0x4e650000)]
  0x4bf9b800 JavaThread "pool-2-thread-8" [_thread_blocked, id=2984, stack(0x4e570000,0x4e5e0000)]
  0x4bf9ac00 JavaThread "pool-2-thread-7" [_thread_blocked, id=2064, stack(0x4e500000,0x4e570000)]
  0x4bf0cc00 JavaThread "pool-2-thread-6" [_thread_blocked, id=3100, stack(0x4e490000,0x4e500000)]
  0x49386400 JavaThread "pool-2-thread-5" [_thread_blocked, id=2892, stack(0x4e420000,0x4e490000)]
  0x48f13400 JavaThread "pool-2-thread-4" [_thread_blocked, id=1660, stack(0x4e3b0000,0x4e420000)]
  0x492a7400 JavaThread "pool-2-thread-3" [_thread_blocked, id=1916, stack(0x4e340000,0x4e3b0000)]
  0x4c3dc800 JavaThread "pool-2-thread-2" [_thread_blocked, id=956, stack(0x4e2d0000,0x4e340000)]
  0x4c3d3800 JavaThread "MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager cleanup" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2944, stack(0x4e260000,0x4e2d0000)]
  0x4924f000 JavaThread "pool-2-thread-1" [_thread_blocked, id=3920, stack(0x4e1f0000,0x4e260000)]
  0x4c3b4400 JavaThread "TSDRClient multithreaded operation monitoring thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2696, stack(0x4e180000,0x4e1f0000)]
  0x4c054000 JavaThread "UMA Logger 'DataUploadServlet' Background Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3928, stack(0x4e110000,0x4e180000)]
  0x49307400 JavaThread "UMA Logger 'DataUploadServlet' extra file logging thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3032, stack(0x4e0a0000,0x4e110000)]
  0x4c2d1400 JavaThread "UMA Logger 'WriteLog' extra file logging thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3056, stack(0x4e030000,0x4e0a0000)]
  0x4c022c00 JavaThread "UMA Logger 'URM' extra file logging thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4000, stack(0x4dfc0000,0x4e030000)]
  0x48e45400 JavaThread "pool-1-thread-15" [_thread_blocked, id=1800, stack(0x4d780000,0x4d7f0000)]
  0x4c000400 JavaThread "pool-1-thread-14" [_thread_blocked, id=3264, stack(0x4d710000,0x4d780000)]
  0x4937b800 JavaThread "pool-1-thread-13" [_thread_blocked, id=3444, stack(0x4d5c0000,0x4d630000)]
  0x4c0c4000 JavaThread "pool-1-thread-12" [_thread_blocked, id=2252, stack(0x4d6a0000,0x4d710000)]
  0x4c0d2c00 JavaThread "pool-1-thread-11" [_thread_blocked, id=1284, stack(0x4d630000,0x4d6a0000)]
  0x49318800 JavaThread "pool-1-thread-10" [_thread_blocked, id=2124, stack(0x4d550000,0x4d5c0000)]
  0x4c097400 JavaThread "pool-1-thread-9" [_thread_blocked, id=2728, stack(0x4d4e0000,0x4d550000)]
  0x4931ec00 JavaThread "pool-1-thread-8" [_thread_blocked, id=1788, stack(0x4d470000,0x4d4e0000)]
  0x48e48000 JavaThread "pool-1-thread-7" [_thread_blocked, id=3224, stack(0x4d400000,0x4d470000)]
  0x49186c00 JavaThread "pool-1-thread-6" [_thread_blocked, id=3384, stack(0x4d390000,0x4d400000)]
  0x4beeb400 JavaThread "pool-1-thread-5" [_thread_blocked, id=3976, stack(0x4d320000,0x4d390000)]
  0x4bfba400 JavaThread "pool-1-thread-4" [_thread_blocked, id=3168, stack(0x4d240000,0x4d2b0000)]
  0x48fc4c00 JavaThread "http-apr-8443-exec-10" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3516, stack(0x4d1d0000,0x4d240000)]
  0x493a5800 JavaThread "http-apr-8443-exec-9" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3192, stack(0x4d160000,0x4d1d0000)]
  0x493b5400 JavaThread "pool-1-thread-3" [_thread_blocked, id=3540, stack(0x4d0f0000,0x4d160000)]
  0x4c0c3400 JavaThread "http-apr-8443-exec-8" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3556, stack(0x4d080000,0x4d0f0000)]
  0x49390c00 JavaThread "http-apr-8443-exec-7" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3440, stack(0x4d010000,0x4d080000)]
  0x4c1a8800 JavaThread "http-apr-8443-exec-6" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2760, stack(0x4cea0000,0x4cf10000)]
  0x48e66000 JavaThread "pool-1-thread-2" [_thread_blocked, id=2056, stack(0x4cdc0000,0x4ce30000)]
  0x48e49800 JavaThread "http-apr-8443-exec-5" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2344, stack(0x4cd50000,0x4cdc0000)]
  0x48e4a400 JavaThread "http-apr-8443-exec-4" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1860, stack(0x4cce0000,0x4cd50000)]
  0x49296400 JavaThread "MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager cleanup" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4008, stack(0x4cc00000,0x4cc70000)]
  0x4bf6bc00 JavaThread "http-apr-8443-exec-3" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=460, stack(0x4cb90000,0x4cc00000)]
  0x4c2f0400 JavaThread "pool-1-thread-1" [_thread_blocked, id=1520, stack(0x4cb20000,0x4cb90000)]
  0x4c2ae400 JavaThread "TSDRClient multithreaded operation monitoring thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4064, stack(0x4cab0000,0x4cb20000)]
  0x4c037c00 JavaThread "UMA Logger 'DataUploadServlet' Background Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3952, stack(0x4ca40000,0x4cab0000)]
  0x48fe7800 JavaThread "UMA Logger 'URM' extra file logging thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4020, stack(0x4c8f0000,0x4c960000)]
  0x49329800 JavaThread "http-apr-8443-exec-2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3564, stack(0x4c880000,0x4c8f0000)]
  0x49329400 JavaThread "http-apr-8443-exec-1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3604, stack(0x4c7a0000,0x4c810000)]
  0x49364400 JavaThread "AWT-Windows" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=2608, stack(0x4c810000,0x4c880000)]
  0x4c193400 JavaThread "Java2D Disposer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2712, stack(0x4c730000,0x4c7a0000)]
  0x4bf20800 JavaThread "TSDR maintenance thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2596, stack(0x4c6b0000,0x4c720000)]
  0x4930cc00 JavaThread "MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager cleanup" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1212, stack(0x4bdd0000,0x4be40000)]
  0x492f3c00 JavaThread "ajp-apr-8009-AsyncTimeout" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3868, stack(0x4b900000,0x4b970000)]
  0x492f2400 JavaThread "ajp-apr-8009-Acceptor-0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=3864, stack(0x4b890000,0x4b900000)]
  0x49288800 JavaThread "ajp-apr-8009-CometPoller-7" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3860, stack(0x4b820000,0x4b890000)]
  0x49287000 JavaThread "ajp-apr-8009-CometPoller-6" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3856, stack(0x4b7b0000,0x4b820000)]
  0x49282800 JavaThread "ajp-apr-8009-CometPoller-5" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3852, stack(0x4b740000,0x4b7b0000)]
  0x00c3cc00 JavaThread "ajp-apr-8009-CometPoller-4" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3848, stack(0x4b6d0000,0x4b740000)]
  0x00c3b400 JavaThread "ajp-apr-8009-CometPoller-3" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3844, stack(0x4b660000,0x4b6d0000)]
  0x00c3a000 JavaThread "ajp-apr-8009-CometPoller-2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3840, stack(0x4b5f0000,0x4b660000)]
  0x48fa4c00 JavaThread "ajp-apr-8009-CometPoller-1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3836, stack(0x4b580000,0x4b5f0000)]
  0x48fa3400 JavaThread "ajp-apr-8009-CometPoller-0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3832, stack(0x4b510000,0x4b580000)]
  0x48e52400 JavaThread "ajp-apr-8009-Poller-7" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3828, stack(0x4b4a0000,0x4b510000)]
  0x48e51000 JavaThread "ajp-apr-8009-Poller-6" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3824, stack(0x4b430000,0x4b4a0000)]
  0x48fd6800 JavaThread "ajp-apr-8009-Poller-5" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3820, stack(0x4b3c0000,0x4b430000)]
  0x49031c00 JavaThread "ajp-apr-8009-Poller-4" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3816, stack(0x4b350000,0x4b3c0000)]
  0x49030400 JavaThread "ajp-apr-8009-Poller-3" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3812, stack(0x4b2e0000,0x4b350000)]
  0x49036c00 JavaThread "ajp-apr-8009-Poller-2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3808, stack(0x4b270000,0x4b2e0000)]
  0x4934c400 JavaThread "ajp-apr-8009-Poller-1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3804, stack(0x4b200000,0x4b270000)]
  0x4934b400 JavaThread "ajp-apr-8009-Poller-0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3800, stack(0x4b190000,0x4b200000)]
  0x4927b400 JavaThread "http-apr-8443-AsyncTimeout" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3796, stack(0x4b120000,0x4b190000)]
  0x4927bc00 JavaThread "http-apr-8443-Acceptor-0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=3792, stack(0x4b0b0000,0x4b120000)]
  0x4927a000 JavaThread "http-apr-8443-CometPoller-7" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3788, stack(0x4b040000,0x4b0b0000)]
  0x48e76800 JavaThread "http-apr-8443-CometPoller-0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3760, stack(0x4ad30000,0x4ada0000)]
  0x48e75000 JavaThread "http-apr-8443-Poller-7" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3756, stack(0x4acc0000,0x4ad30000)]
  0x491b8400 JavaThread "http-apr-8443-Poller-2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3736, stack(0x4a690000,0x4a700000)]
  0x491b7000 JavaThread "http-apr-8443-Poller-1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3732, stack(0x4a620000,0x4a690000)]
  0x4931a800 JavaThread "http-apr-8443-Poller-0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3728, stack(0x4a5b0000,0x4a620000)]
  0x4911f800 JavaThread "http-apr-8080-AsyncTimeout" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3716, stack(0x4a460000,0x4a4d0000)]
  0x490f2400 JavaThread "http-apr-8080-Acceptor-0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=3712, stack(0x4a3f0000,0x4a460000)]
  0x00c87400 JavaThread "http-apr-8080-Sendfile-0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3708, stack(0x4a380000,0x4a3f0000)]
  0x4925c400 JavaThread "http-apr-8080-CometPoller-7" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3704, stack(0x4a310000,0x4a380000)]
  0x48fb4400 JavaThread "http-apr-8080-CometPoller-6" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3700, stack(0x4a2a0000,0x4a310000)]
  0x490db400 JavaThread "http-apr-8080-CometPoller-2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3684, stack(0x4a0e0000,0x4a150000)]
  0x4925e400 JavaThread "http-apr-8080-CometPoller-1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3680, stack(0x4a070000,0x4a0e0000)]
  0x49299400 JavaThread "http-apr-8080-CometPoller-0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3676, stack(0x4a000000,0x4a070000)]
  0x492af400 JavaThread "http-apr-8080-Poller-7" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3672, stack(0x49f90000,0x4a000000)]
  0x49191400 JavaThread "http-apr-8080-Poller-6" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=3668, stack(0x49f20000,0x49f90000)]
  0x49214400 JavaThread "http-apr-8080-Poller-5" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=3664, stack(0x49cb0000,0x49d20000)]
  0x49358800 JavaThread "http-apr-8080-Poller-4" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3660, stack(0x49c40000,0x49cb0000)]
  0x49367400 JavaThread "http-apr-8080-Poller-3" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=3656, stack(0x49bd0000,0x49c40000)]
  0x49207400 JavaThread "http-apr-8080-Poller-2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3652, stack(0x49b60000,0x49bd0000)]
  0x493ad800 JavaThread "http-apr-8080-Poller-1" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=3648, stack(0x49af0000,0x49b60000)]
  0x49133000 JavaThread "http-apr-8080-Poller-0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3644, stack(0x49a80000,0x49af0000)]
  0x48e41400 JavaThread "ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3636, stack(0x49a10000,0x49a80000)]
  0x49146800 JavaThread "Timer-0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3496, stack(0x499a0000,0x49a10000)]
  0x49168400 JavaThread "UMA Logger 'default' Background Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3316, stack(0x49930000,0x499a0000)]
  0x49178c00 JavaThread "UMA Logger 'default' extra file logging thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3312, stack(0x497b0000,0x49820000)]
  0x49071800 JavaThread "GC Daemon" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2292, stack(0x496d0000,0x49740000)]
  0x00c29000 JavaThread "Low Memory Detector" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1256, stack(0x48d50000,0x48dc0000)]
  0x00c1a000 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1248, stack(0x48ce0000,0x48d50000)]
  0x00c18800 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1184, stack(0x48c70000,0x48ce0000)]
  0x00c17400 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1236, stack(0x48c00000,0x48c70000)]
=>0x00c06800 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=352, stack(0x48b90000,0x48c00000)]
  0x00c05400 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=344, stack(0x00d00000,0x00d70000)]
  0x00616c00 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=2008, stack(0x006b0000,0x00720000)]

Other Threads:
  0x00c01800 VMThread [stack: 0x00c90000,0x00d00000] [id=340]
  0x00c2bc00 WatcherThread [stack: 0x48dc0000,0x48e30000] [id=1264]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
 def new generation   total 114688K, used 1727K [0x02d90000, 0x0aa00000, 0x182e0000)
  eden space 101952K,   1% used [0x02d90000, 0x02f3fdd0, 0x09120000)
  from space 12736K,   0% used [0x09120000, 0x09120000, 0x09d90000)
  to   space 12736K,   0% used [0x09d90000, 0x09d90000, 0x0aa00000)
 tenured generation   total 254504K, used 71377K [0x182e0000, 0x27b6a000, 0x42d90000)
   the space 254504K,  28% used [0x182e0000, 0x1c894608, 0x1c894800, 0x27b6a000)
 compacting perm gen  total 57856K, used 57651K [0x42d90000, 0x46610000, 0x46d90000)
   the space 57856K,  99% used [0x42d90000, 0x465dcec0, 0x465dd000, 0x46610000)
No shared spaces configured.

Code Cache  [0x00d90000, 0x01dc8000, 0x02d90000)
 total_blobs=5965 nmethods=5670 adapters=230 free_code_cache=16836096 largest_free_block=62784

Dynamic libraries:
0x00400000 - 0x00417000     D:\product.packaged\Tomcat7.0\bin\Tomcat7.exe
0x7c910000 - 0x7c9c9000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll
0x7c800000 - 0x7c908000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\kernel32.dll
0x77da0000 - 0x77e4a000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x77e50000 - 0x77ee3000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\RPCRT4.dll
0x77fc0000 - 0x77fd1000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\Secur32.dll
0x7e670000 - 0x7ee91000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\SHELL32.dll
0x77ef0000 - 0x77f39000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\GDI32.dll
0x7e360000 - 0x7e3f1000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\USER32.dll
0x77be0000 - 0x77c38000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\msvcrt.dll
0x77f40000 - 0x77fb6000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
0x76330000 - 0x7634d000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x773a0000 - 0x774a3000     C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.2600.6028_x-ww_61e65202\comctl32.dll
0x5d450000 - 0x5d4ea000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\comctl32.dll
0x6d7f0000 - 0x6daa0000     D:\product.packaged\jre6\bin\client\jvm.dll
0x76af0000 - 0x76b1e000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WINMM.dll
0x7c340000 - 0x7c396000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\MSVCR71.dll
0x6d7a0000 - 0x6d7ac000     D:\product.packaged\jre6\bin\verify.dll
0x6d320000 - 0x6d33f000     D:\product.packaged\jre6\bin\java.dll
0x6d7e0000 - 0x6d7ef000     D:\product.packaged\jre6\bin\zip.dll
0x774b0000 - 0x775ee000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\ole32.dll
0x5b0f0000 - 0x5b128000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\uxtheme.dll
0x778f0000 - 0x779e4000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\SETUPAPI.dll
0x6d550000 - 0x6d559000     D:\product.packaged\jre6\bin\management.dll
0x49430000 - 0x4954c000     D:\product.packaged\Tomcat7.0\bin\tcnative-1.dll
0x76bb0000 - 0x76bbb000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\PSAPI.DLL
0x71a10000 - 0x71a27000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WS2_32.dll
0x71a00000 - 0x71a08000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WS2HELP.dll
0x719b0000 - 0x719f0000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\MSWSOCK.dll
0x68000000 - 0x68036000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\rsaenh.dll
0x6d780000 - 0x6d788000     D:\product.packaged\jre6\bin\sunmscapi.dll
0x77a50000 - 0x77ae6000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\CRYPT32.dll
0x77af0000 - 0x77b02000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\MSASN1.dll
0x49740000 - 0x49783000     C:\Programme\Avira\AntiVir Desktop\avsda.dll
0x76d20000 - 0x76d39000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\IPHLPAPI.DLL
0x66710000 - 0x66769000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\hnetcfg.dll
0x719f0000 - 0x719f8000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\wshtcpip.dll
0x6d600000 - 0x6d613000     D:\product.packaged\jre6\bin\net.dll
0x76ee0000 - 0x76f07000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\DNSAPI.dll
0x76f70000 - 0x76f78000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\winrnr.dll
0x76f20000 - 0x76f4d000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WLDAP32.dll
0x76f80000 - 0x76f86000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\rasadhlp.dll
0x6d000000 - 0x6d14c000     D:\product.packaged\jre6\bin\awt.dll
0x72f70000 - 0x72f96000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WINSPOOL.DRV
0x6d230000 - 0x6d27f000     D:\product.packaged\jre6\bin\fontmanager.dll
0x6d620000 - 0x6d629000     D:\product.packaged\jre6\bin\nio.dll
0x6d1a0000 - 0x6d1c3000     D:\product.packaged\jre6\bin\dcpr.dll
0x6d440000 - 0x6d465000     D:\product.packaged\jre6\bin\jpeg.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Dcatalina.home=D:\product.packaged\Tomcat7.0 -Dcatalina.base=D:\product.packaged\Tomcat7.0 -Djava.endorsed.dirs=D:\product.packaged\Tomcat7.0\endorsed -Djava.io.tmpdir=D:\product.packaged\Tomcat7.0\temp -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.util.logging.config.file=D:\product.packaged\Tomcat7.0\conf\logging.properties -Xmx1024m 
java_command: <unknown>
Launcher Type: generic

Environment Variables:
PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;d:\product.packaged\jre6\bin;d:\product.packaged\R-2.12.1\bin;d:\product.packaged\cygwin\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=x86 Family 6 Model 26 Stepping 5, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows XP Build 2600 Service Pack 3

CPU:total 4 (4 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 6 model 26 stepping 5, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt

Memory: 4k page, physical 3145192k(1976584k free), swap 7171332k(5981488k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (20.12-b01) for windows-x86 JRE (1.6.0_37-b06), built on Sep 24 2012 12:44:35 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 7.1 (VS2003)

time: Sun Dec 09 13:00:49 2012
elapsed time: 875693 seconds
```

Comment: Looks like a segmentation fault, based on the ExceptionCode.

Comment: thanks Mikaveli. That would hint to an issue with memory management? I had that impression also, probably some race condition with garbage collection and imageio buffering? May this http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/KnownIssues#ImageIOIssues is related, although I would expect that a product like cewolf would take care of such a workaround, if commonly needed. Also this is a bit worse than "strange exceptions"...

Comment: Don't know what your code looks like, but do any of these hints help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7689526/exception-access-violation-0xc0000005-jvm-from-jni

Comment: thanks for the link, but unfortunately I don't believe that those suggestions help here, as I didn't write the native code part myself. The native code is packaged Tomcat APR and/or Java imageio native code - widespread heavily used JNI code. I don't think mistakes as in the answers for that question would still be in there - otherwise such Tomcat JVM crashes would probably happen all the time...